# "Warning: exec() has been disabled" .workaround to enable it on shared hosting?

Tags: php, exec, cpanel, shared-hosting

I have a situation where lots of backdoor is hiding on my cpanel account, I host several domain in several hosting company, now I find that using php script to search string suspected backdoor is very efective and useful, I use this script

```
<?php 
    $formatted = "";
    $output = array();
    $command = "";
    if (!empty($_POST['grep_pattern'])) {
        $command = "grep -RnIi " . escapeshellarg($_POST['grep_pattern']) . " . | grep -v \".svn\"";
        $result = -1;
        $return_code = -1;
        $result = exec($command, $output, $return_code);
        foreach($output as $line) {
            $formatted .= htmlspecialchars($line) . "\n";
        }
    }    
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>PHP grep</title>
    </head>
    <body id="" onload="">
        <form action="php_grep.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <label for="grep_pattern">Grep for: </label><input type="text" name="grep_pattern" value="" id="grep_pattern">
            <p><input type="submit" value="grep it! &rarr;"></p>
        </form>

<?php if (!empty($command)) { ?>        
        Command: <code><?php echo htmlspecialchars($command); ?></code><br>
        Output: 
        <pre><?php echo $formatted; ?></pre>
        Last line of result was: <code><?php echo htmlspecialchars($result); ?></code><br>
        Return code is: <code><?php echo $return_code; ?></code><br>
        Number of results: <code><?php echo count($output); ?></code>
<?php } ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

but on the last cpanel account which hosted on local hosting provider ,script cannot run

Warning: exec() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/xxxxxx/public_html/grep.php on line 9

I did searching on google and forum,most of them suggested that i contacted hosting provider to enable the exec function..which I did but ,the hosting doesn't approve my request so I'm stuck

Can you give me suggestion what should I do? Does cpanel has function similar to script I mention above without using exec? Sorry if the question kinda stupid as my knowledge regarding computer or network related stuff not very good.

Comment: Please tag the question CPanel and PHP too. Also what do you mean by backdoor as normally that would mean a malicious program installed by someone else.

Comment: i mean php script like c99 or things like that,on bluehost i was able to run the script and "clean" my account (hopefully) by searching string like base64_decode...but i also find out that they put script to upload somewhere in public_html im suspected that script is being used to spawn another php backdoor...i found grep really usefull ,but on my another cpanel i got error like i mention above,exec disabled i guessed